# Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime when using react-native-canvas with Expo

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, canvas, expo

I seem to be getting Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime when using react-native-canvas in a new Expo project.

To recreate the issue, paste in `npm install react-native-canvas` and `npx expo install react-native-webview`.

Anyways, here's the code which is causing this error. It's so strange, I've got no idea where it's stemming from.

Code:

```
import {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import {SafeAreaView} from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import Canvas from 'react-native-canvas'
import {StyleSheet} from "react-native";

export default function Foundation() {
  const ref = useRef<Canvas | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const ctx = ref.current.getContext('2d')

      if (ctx) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
        ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 100, 100)
      }
    }
  }, [ref])

  return (
    <Canvas ref={ref} style={styles.canvas} />
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    height: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  canvas: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  }
})
```